# Very strange font display issue in .NET WinForms application

Tags: .net, winforms, fonts, corrupt

I have a user who has reported a very strange issue with font rendering in the open source application I develop, mRemoteNG. This is the only user out of tens of thousands that has this problem as far as I know.

Here is a link to the issue (including screenshots) on the project's JIRA:

[MR-616 - Incorrect font rendering](https://mremoteng.atlassian.net/browse/MR-616)

The user has reinstalled the application, run a system file check, verified the font being used is installed and working correctly, switched to the English translation of the application, and checked the FontSubstitutes registry key. Everything checks out fine, but the fonts still aren't displayed correctly.

I've searched all over and can't find any similar issues. I even tried searching Google Images for similar corruption. At this point, I can't think of anything else to try.

The application is written in VB.NET and uses WinForms.

[Source code on Github](https://github.com/rmcardle/mRemoteNG)

Answer (score 0):

I m not allowed to add a comment yet; I just wanted to ask a question that may point to your problem. Do you generate the text dynamically? (i.e by extracting from a dll manifest)
if yes then you might want to use the Encoding.UTF8.

You need to use the UTF8 as you can see in the following links  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
and also this link  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The text is stored in [resource files](https://github.com/rmcardle/mRemoteNG/blob/develop/mRemoteV1/Language/Language.resx) and accessed using [the code automatically generated by Visual Studio](https://github.com/rmcardle/mRemoteNG/blob/develop/mRemoteV1/Language/Language.Designer.vb).

Comment: You should use the Encoding.UTF8 to output your text from the resource file

Comment: You need to use the UTF8 as you can see in the following links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbx3z216(v=vs.110).aspx   and also this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The encoding is correct. The program has translations in Chinese, Russian, and other languages that would not work if the encoding was wrong. Keep in mind this is only one user who is having trouble out of tens of thousands.